# Point in Probability that something is known to be Wrong

Tags: probability

How many times would you need to lose a game with 50% odds before knowing that something was wrong with the game? I found the odds of losing 59 times in a row to be 1 in 5.764 x 10^17 which is still technically feasible; so at what point can you draw the line and know that there must be something awry?

Comment: You can never know.

Answer (score 1):

This is the question that [statistical hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) tries to answer.

First, you formulate a hypothesis: "This is a fair game with a 50% chance of winning each round."

Next, you collect some data, perhaps by playing 59 rounds of the game and finding that you lose every time.

Finally, you perform a test in order to make a "best guess" as to whether or not the hypothesis is correct.

An appropriate testing method to use here would be a "one-proportion $z$-test". I don't have a good reference for this; if anyone could edit this answer to point at a good reference, that would be really helpful.

Comment: It is an important tenet of experimental design that one chooses the statistical test in advance of doing the experiment, including a declaration of what *significance level* will be set to reject the null hypothesis.  The *z*-test is commonly used in connection with experiments which are modelled as Bernoulli trials.  I can add some links to support Tanner's Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The expected outcome for a game with a $50\%$ chance of winning is naturally $50\%$ of $n$ the number of trials. Normally a margin of error surrounds the expected value at a given significance level outside of which is considered evidence that something is wrong (not a 50% chance).

Let's assume we will toss a supposedly fair coin 100 times and we get 40 heads. Is this significant at the 95% confidence level which means statistically significant if the probability p of the outcome is less than .05

$$z = \frac{\widehat p - p_0}{\sqrt{\frac{p_0(1-p_0)}{n}}}$$

$$z = \frac{.40 - .50}{\sqrt{\frac{(.5\cdot .5)}{100}}}$$

$z = -2.0$ and from a $Z$ table $p = .0455$

We therefore have evidence that the coin is not fair as $.0455 < .05$

We can never be $100\%$ confident that this is the case as the possibility of getting this result by chance, given the coin is fair, is $.05$ or less.

We can be more certain that the coin is not fair by increasing $n$ and the level of significance but there is no definitive point at which you can draw an line and say anything beyond this is $100\%$ certain. All we have is a spectrum of ever increasing certainties all less than $100\%$.

Comment: So is there a point when you can conclude that the coin is not fair? Or is it when the probability is outside of the Z-table reading for 95% confidence that you can say that the coin is not fair

Comment: Being outside the 95% confidence interval is evidence. You can repeat the test again and improve the evidence and hence the probability of it not being fair  and be almost 100% sure, but like I said, there is no definitive point where this occurs. 95%, 99%, 99.5%..........etc etc.